# Why is the first part of my program slowing down the second part? Slow garbage collection?

Tags: java, postgresql

My program looks like this:

```
String intermediateResult = foo(int depth, String input);
String finalResult = bar(intermediateResult);
```

-> 'foo()' connects to a  postgres database and constructs trees and graphs based on the input and the specified depth, higher depth results in a longer computation time and more memory usage of foo, as more complex datastructures will be built

-> 'bar()' takes the output of 'foo()', which resembles an SQL-query and performs some more database operations, basically validating the result of 'foo()'

QUESTION:

Why is the computation time of 'bar()' influenced by the depth of the computation of 'foo()', even though the exact same intermediateResult is returned? Is the Java garbage collection taking more time to clean up the datastructures left behind by 'foo()'? Or is it because of the Database?

Comment: How did you benchmark the times?  Did you print the system time before, in between, and after?

Comment: It's taking considerably more time, up to 30 seconds difference. I used Timers to benchmark exact times, but I also have log4j outputs to keep track of the program state.

Comment: Could you try just using `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead?

Comment: Here is a simple test you can also run: Measure the execution time of `bar()` using 2 different hard coded strings in a unit test.  This will remove the database dependency.

Comment: Have you tried any form of code analyser to see where the problem lies?

Comment: The causes of performance problems are best identified with a **Profiler**. *Guessing* at the cause of performance problems is not an efficient approach if the program is not trivial.

Comment: I agree you should use a profiler. As per GC impact, I doubt a single GC  would add 30 sec. Is it possible that the first phase is creating objects still alive when the second phase starts, causing a low memory situation that wold result in GC called multiple times? To verify this modify your code to print amount of free mem before phase one, add a forced GC after phase 1, and print new free mem. If second print is considerably lower and dangerously close to available mem, then that would be your problen.